# how to change bootstrap-sass defaults

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-sass

I am working on a ruby on rails projects using rails 3.2 and bootstrap 3. The gem i am using is bootstrap-sass and it is the most current one.  I am trying to change the default attributes of bootstrap's components in my stylesheets file.  In the gem's documentation, it stated that I can change certain things of bootstrap before I use the:

@import "bootstrap";

i wanted to create a black border around bootstrap's thumbnails and make the

---

black by default.

So before the import statement, I added:

$thumbnail-border: #000000 5px;
$hr-border: #000000;

Then, I placed the variables in the appropriate bootstrap classes and I get nothing.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We can't adjust the thumbnail border width through the `$thumbnail-border` variable.  The [Bootstrap definition](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables) of this variable is "Thumbnail border color".  In the `bootstrap-sass` gem we can see the variable is used here in [_thumbnails.scss](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_thumbnails.scss):

```
border: 1px solid $thumbnail-border;
```

So we can only adjust the color and to do so we would only need to have these lines in the `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss` file:

```
$thumbnail-border: #000000;
@import "bootstrap";
```

To override both the size and color we'd have to do something like this in `application.css.scss` instead:

```
@import "bootstrap";
.thumbnail {
  border: 5px solid #000000;
}
```

That will keep the other thumbnail styles but will override the border values.